# Convergent series over countable set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> **Definition**:
>
> Let be $M$ a countable set. Then $\sum\limits_{k\in M}a_k$ converges if there exists a bijection $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to M$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{\varphi(k)}$ converges absolutely. (We know that the particular choice of $\varphi$ doesn't matter)

Let's assume $M_1,M_2$ are both disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Further, we assume that the three series $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}a_k$, $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}a_k$ and  $\sum\limits_{k\in M_2}a_k$ converge. Show that
$$
\sum\limits_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}a_k=\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}a_k+\sum\limits_{k\in M_2}a_k.
$$

---

**My new approach:**

Let's define:

$a_k^{M_1\cup M_2}:=\begin{cases}
     a_k & \text{ if } k \in M_1\cup M_2\\
     0 & \text{ if } k\notin M_1\cup M_2,\end{cases}$

and for $i=\{1,2\}$:

$a_k^{M_i}:=\begin{cases}
     a_k & \text{ if } k \in M_i\\
     0 & \text{ if } k\notin M_i.\end{cases}$

There exists an index $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_0}a_{\varphi(k)}-\sum\limits_{k\in M_i}a_k\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Further, we choose $m_0\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough such that $\{\varphi(1),\varphi(2),\cdots,\varphi(n_0)\}\subseteq \{1,2,\cdots, m_0\}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=m_0}^{\infty}|a_k^{M_i}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (we know that it converges absolutely due to comparison with $\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}}a_k$). It follows:
$$\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_0}a_k^{M_i}-\sum\limits_{k\in M_i}a_k\right|\leq\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_0}a_k^{M_i}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_0}a_{\varphi(k)}\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_0}a_{\varphi(k)}-\sum\limits_{k\in M_i}a_k\right|< \sum\limits_{k=m_0}^{\infty}|a_k^{M_i}|+\frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.$$

For an arbitrary $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $a_k^{M_1\cup M_2}=a_k^{M_1}+a_k^{M_2}$ so it follows $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^{M_1\cup M_2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^{M_1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^{M_2}\implies \sum\limits_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}a_k=\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}a_k+\sum\limits_{k\in M_2}a_k$.

---

Is this correct? It looks a little bit too simple... This whole thing with countable index sets still seems strange to me. Maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: What if $M_1$ is the set of primes, and $M_2$ is the set of squares of primes? Then $M_1\cup M_2\subsetneqq\Bbb N$, so there is no $\varphi:\Bbb N\to M_1\cup M_2$ such that $\varphi(k)=k$ for all $k$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you, I have edited my question, hope it's o.k. now. Any further feedback is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1,2$ let $\varphi_i:\Bbb N\to M_i$ be a bijection, and let

$$\varphi:\Bbb N:M_1\cup M_2:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
\varphi_1\left(\frac{n}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\varphi_2\left(\frac{n-1}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$

(Note that for me $\Bbb N$ includes $0$.) It’s not hard to verify that $\varphi$ is a bijection such that

$$\langle\varphi(0),\varphi(1),\varphi(2),\varphi(3),\ldots\rangle=\langle\varphi_1(0),\varphi_2(0),\varphi_1(1),\varphi_2(1),\ldots\rangle\,,$$

so that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_{\varphi(k)}=\sum_{k=0}^na_{\varphi_1(k)}+\sum_{k=0}^na_{\varphi_2(k)}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Let

$$\ell=\sum_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}a_k=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}a_{\varphi(k)}$$

and

$$\ell_i=\sum_{k\in M_i}a_k=\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}a_{\varphi_i(k)}$$

for $i=1,2$; we want to show that $\ell=\ell_1+\ell_2$.

Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that

$$\left|\ell_i-\sum_{k=0}^{n_\epsilon}a_{\varphi_i(k)}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2$$

for $i=1,2$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\left|(\ell_1+\ell_2)-\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_{\varphi(k)}\right|&=\left|(\ell_1+\ell_2)-\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_{\varphi_1(k)}+\sum_{k=0}^na_{\varphi_2(k)}\right)\right|\\
&\le\left|\ell_1-\sum_{k=0}^na_{\varphi_1(k)}\right|+\left|\ell_2-\sum_{k=0}^na_{varphi_2(k)}\right|\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2\\
&=\epsilon\,,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_{\varphi(k)}=\ell_1+\ell_2\,.$$

Comment: Is it really necessary to go this way? I have added a new approach to my question which seems faster and more elegant.

Comment: @Philipp: That depends entirely on what results you already have available. Have you actually already proved any result that lets you conclude without any argument that $\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k^{M_1}=\sum_{k\in M_1}a_k$, for instance?

Comment: Why do I need any further results to make this conclusion? I am only adding zero's. The only result I use is that the order of the summands $a_k$ of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$  doesn't matter due to absolute convergence. Indeed this is the definition of convergence of $\sum\limits_{k\in M_i}a_k$.

Comment: @Philipp: But you aren’t simply changing the order of the summands: you’re inserting **new** summands. Yes, they are all $0$, but the fact that the new series has the same sum certainly requires proof.

Comment: I thought it would be obvious that this is true. I have added a few details to make it clear. Is it now correct?

Comment: @Philipp: When you choose $m_0$ large enough so that $\sum\limits_{k\ge m_0}\left|a_k^{M_i}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2$, you’re very nearly assuming your conclusion: $\sum_{k\ge m_0}\left|a_k^{M_i}\right|$ is not known to be convergent, so you cannot at that point justify the existence of such an $m_0$. Proving that it is convergent is actually quite similar to proving that inserting all those zeroes doesn’t change the sum.

Comment: I think I mistakenly assumed that $\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}}a_k$ is convergent. Only under this assumption $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^{M_i}$ converges absolutely by comparison because for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|a_k^{M_i}|\leq |a_k|$ and $\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}}a_k$ converges by assumption.  In that case all we need to prove is that both limits $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^{M_i}$ and $\sum\limits_{k\in M_i}a_k $ attain the same value.

Comment: By taking $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}a_{\varphi(k)}$ you restrict your proof to odd index numbers. To me it's kind of obvious that your proof also applies to the case when the index number is even (with a slight change). Would you suggest mentioning this case from the vantage point of an undergraduate student?

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, it’s probably safer to do so. You could either make the modification or use the (easily proved) fact that the terms $a_{\varphi(k)}$ are going to $0$ as $k$ increases.

Comment: If we only knew that $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}a_k$ is convergent. How do I rigorously show that $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}a_k$ is convergent? I would go for monotonicity and boundedness. $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}|a_k|$ is monotone. But how do I rigorously prove that $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}|a_k|$ is bounded by $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}|a_k|$? Intuitively it's clear because every $|a_k$| of  $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}|a_k|$ appears in $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}|a_k|$ but this argument doesn't sound very precise, does it?

Comment: @Philipp: If $\sum_{k\in M_1\cup M_2}a_k$ converges, there is a bijection $f:\Bbb N\to M_1\cup M_2$ s.t. $\sum_ka_{\varphi(k)}$ converges absolutely. Let $b_k=a_k$ for $k\in M_1$ and $b_k=0$ for $k\in M_2$; then $\sum_kb_{\varphi(k)}$ converges absolutely, since $\sum_{k=0}^n|b_{\varphi(k)}|\le\sum_{k=0}^n|a_{\varphi(k)}|$ for all $n$.

Comment: But how do we know that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_{k}=\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}a_k$? The series  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_{k}$ is essentially the same series I had defined earlier ($\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k^{M_1}$) and showing $\sum\limits_{k\in M_1}a_k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k^{M_1}$ didn't work out.

Comment: @Philipp: You show that there is an order-preserving bijection $\psi:\Bbb N\to\varphi^{-1}[M_1]$ and then show that the sequences of partial sums of $\sum_k|b_{\varphi(k)}|$ and $\sum_k|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|$ have the same limit.

Comment: For $n>n_0:\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$
and we choose $m$ such that $\{\varphi(\psi(1)),\cdots, \varphi(\psi(n_0))\}\subseteq\{\varphi(1),\cdots, \varphi(m)\}$. Then,$$\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|b_{\varphi(k)}|-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right|<\epsilon.$$ Is this the way to go? Again it resembles the approach I had used initially? I don't see quite a big difference in both approaches? Why do I need the order preserving bijection?

Comment: @Philipp: The order-preserving bijection makes it much easier to compare partial sums: it’s immediately evident that there is a strictly increasing sequence $\langle n_\ell:\ell\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell}}|b_{\varphi(k)}|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell+1}}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell+2}}|b_{\varphi(k)}|$$ for all $\ell$.

Comment: E.g.
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2}|b_{\varphi(k)}|=|a_4|+0\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{3}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|=|a_4|+|a_6|+|a_9|\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}|b_{\varphi(k)}|=|a_4|+0+|a_6|+|a_9|.
$$
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell}}|b_{\varphi(k)}|\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell +1}}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|$ always holds. But I don't see why there exists a subsequence such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{ n_{2\ell+1}}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{ n_{2\ell+2}}|b_{\varphi(k)}|$ should hold? The series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{ n_{2\ell+2}}|b_{\varphi(k)}|$ might be "filled up" with zeros.

Comment: @Philipp: Because the $a$ sequence is a subsequence of the $b$ sequence, and the terms that it’s missing are all $0$.

Comment: But in my example you accumulate much faster non zero terms with the $a$ sequence than with the $b$ sequence. So I don't understand how this fits together?

Comment: @Philipp: It makes no difference. You just end up with some long gaps in the sequence $\langle n_\ell:\ell\in\Bbb N\rangle$. You simply construct it recursively to make all of those inequalities hold.

Comment: So you choose the next partial sum which corresponds to the index $2\ell+2$ such that  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell+1}}|a_{\psi(\varphi(k))}|\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n_{2\ell+2}}|b_{\varphi(k)}|$?

Comment: @Philipp: Exactly: that’s how you choose the $n_\ell$ with even subscripts.

Comment: Is my approach in the previous comment where I defined the two sets of indices also legit? This was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @Philipp: Something along those lines can be made to work, though I don’t think that you actually wrote what you meant, since you never did anything with the $m$ that you chose.

Comment: For $n>n_0:\left|\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Further, we choose $m_0$ such that $\{\varphi(\psi(1)),\varphi(\psi(2)),\cdots,\varphi(\psi(n_0))\}\subseteq \{\varphi(1),\varphi(2),\cdots,\varphi(m_0)\},$ then for all $m>m_0$ we get:
$$\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}b_{\varphi(k)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right|+\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right|\leq 2\left|\sum\limits_{k=n_0+1}^{\infty}a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}\right|<\epsilon.$$ So both limits are equal. Right?

Comment: @Philipp: You want an upper limit of $n_0$ where you have $n$. The fact that the first absolute value is less than or equal to the last one actually does require an argument if one is truly being rigorous; my approach builds the equivalent in automatically.

Comment: You've showed that a subsequence of $\sum_{k=1}^{∞}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|$ converges as it can be squeezed between two subsequences of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|b_{\varphi(k)}|$. The limits of those three subsequences are equal (squeeze lemma). If a sequence has a convergent subsequence it must be bounded. If a sequence is bounded and monotone then it converges, so $\sum_{k=1}^{∞}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|$ converges. A convergent sequence has the same limit as its convergent subsequence. Hence, $\sum_{k=1}^{∞}|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|=\sum_{k=1}^{∞}|b_{\varphi(k)}|$. Does this wrap up your idea?

Comment: @Philipp: Yep, sounds good.

Comment: For $n>n_0:\sum_{k=n+1}^∞|b_{φ(k)}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let be $m_0$ such that:$\{b_{φ(1)},\cdots, b_{φ(n_0)}\}⊆\{0,a_{\varphi(\psi(1))},\cdots,a_{\varphi(\psi(m_0))}\}$. For $m>m_0:$
$|\sum_{k=1}^m|a_{\varphi(\psi(k))}|-\sum_{k=1}^n|b_{φ(k)}||+|\sum_{k=1}^n|b_{φ(k)}|-\sum_{k=1}^∞|b_{φ(k)}||<2\sum_{k=n_0+1}^∞|b_{φ(k)}|<\epsilon.$All finitely many terms $b_{φ(1)},\cdots, b_{φ(n_0)}$ in the first absolute value are eliminated or $0$, so the remainder of $\sum_{k=1}^n|b_{φ(k)}|$ only consists of terms with $k>n_0$, hence it is bounded by $\sum_{k=n_0+1}^∞|b_{φ(k)}|$.Is this argument legit?